# When designing a custom HTTP 404 error page, how to notify Search Engine of the 404 status?

Tags: asp.net

Search Engine needs to know a file no longer exists in order to update indexes.

One way I tried was to include `Response.StatusCode = 404` in the custom 404 error page's `Page_Load` event, but the result was the custom page could not be loaded.

In the `web.config` file's `<customErrors>` element, there is a `statusCode` attribute, is that a good way to inform the Search Engine about 404 status?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to add it in web.config `<customErrors><error....` because it is easy to maintain in a file then doing inline coding in every page. One big winner if changes are required all you have to do is update the config file and just do a config release instead of the entire solution